# String interning and HashSet in java

Tags: java, string

I have read about string interning, in which String literals are reused, whereas String object created using `new` aren't reused. This can be seen below when I print `true` and `false` for their equality. To be specific, `(p1==p2)!=p3`, So there are two objects, one pointed by `p1` and `p2`  and another by `p3`. However, when I add them to `HashSet`, all considered same. I was expecting `a.size()` to return `2`, but it returned `1`. Why is this so?

```
package collections;

import java.util.HashSet; 

public class Col {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method1();
    }

    public static void method1()
    {
        HashSet a = new HashSet();
        String p1 = "Person1";
        String p2 = "Person1";
        String p3 = new String("Person1");

        if(p1 == p2)
            System.out.println(true);
        else
            System.out.println(false);


        if(p1 == p3)
            System.out.println(true);
        else
            System.out.println(false);

        a.add(p1);
        a.add(p2);
        a.add(p3);

        System.out.println(a.size());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
true
false
1
```

Comment: You added three strings whose value is `"Person1"`.  Only one unique value was added to the `HashSet`, therefore the `HashSet` has only 1 item.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz i think that the OP was wanting to compare the strings by *reference*, not value.  (`.equals()` compares value, `==` compares reference)

Comment: Shouldn't `p1!=p3` mean that there is at least 2 different values?

Comment: no.  `p1` and `p3` use different string objects, so their *references* will not be equal.

Comment: *Precisely because* two objects with the same values may not have the same identity, nearly all comparisons use `equals` and `hashCode` or `compareTo`. `HashSet` uses `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: yup "their *references* will not be equal", shouldnt that means they will be inserted as two separate objects in HashSet?

Comment: well, no.  `HashSet` stores *values*.  even though `p1` and `p3` have different *references*, their *values* are still the same

Comment: because Hashet uses equals and compareto for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` uses **equality** to keep a unique set of values, not **identity** (i.e., if two objects are `equals` to each other, but not `==`, a `HashSet` will only keep one of them).

You can implement a set that uses identity instead of equality by using the JDK's [`IdentityHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) with a dummy value shared between all keys, in a similar way that `HashSet` is based on `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

> I have read about string interning, in which String literals are reused, whereas String object created using new aren't reused. This can be seen below when I print true and false for their equality. To be specific, (p1==p2)!=p3, So there are two objects, one pointed by p1 and p2 and another by p3. However, when I add them to HashSet, all considered same. I was expecting a.size() to return 2, but it returned 1.

This is right only if you compare String using `==`, the result is different when comparing using `equals()` method. (In doubt, you can test).

When adding into `HashSet`, the comparison method used is `equals()` as its proper for objects. And so, `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are equals.

You can try testing using `equals()` it will output `true`, `true`, `1` instead of `true`, `false`, `1`

Answer (score 0):

p1 and p2 are string literals and they are pointing to the same value because of string pool. So, when we are comparing them using == then they are matching.

p3 is a string object, so when we match using == then it tries to match using reference, so it gives false.

HashSet's add method call HashMap's put method internally. HashMap's put method use hashCode and equals method to set the value in HashMap. String implement hashCode and equals method and provide same hashCode for same value. HashSet contain unique value, so it store only one value.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases where I would recommend learning how to use `javap` to understand how your code is compiled but let me try to explain what is going on under the hood.

When Java compiles that class, it creates instructions for building what is called the **constant pool** for that class. That constant pool will hold a reference to a string with the value *"Person1"*. The compiled logic will also say `p1` and `p2`'s value should be set to the constant pool's reference to that string (the address in memory that it lives in). Calling `p1==p2` will return `true` because they literally have the same exact value. When you call `String p3 = new String("Person1");` you are telling Java to create a new string in a different place in memory which is merely a copy of the original one and then set `p3`'s value as a reference to the place in memory that the new string object lives in. So if you call `p1 == p3` it will return `false` because what you are saying is "does `p1`'s location in memory equals `p2`'s location in memory?"

As others have pointed out, if you called `p1.equals(p3)` it returns `true` because `.equals` compares the **string values** instead of the **references**. And a HashSet will see them all the same because it uses the method `.hashCode` which is similar to `.equals` in the sense that it generates a hash off of the **string value**.

Hopefully that clears up some of the confusion!